# Android attaching .cpm to mp4

Tags: java, android, mp3, mp4, pcm

in my android karaoke app I have a raw pcm data which is the voice of the singer and the mp4 file (music + the audio). Is there a way of attaching the .pcm to the mp4 as well ? so there will be video music and singer's voice ? even mp3 will be fine (just music and singer's voice)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is open a second audio stream for the PCM data, and play it simultaneously with the mp4 file.  This will likely require some thread programming.  I've done this myself and am happy to offer help.